# Mathematical name for related matrix similarity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

Let $A \sim B$ such that $A = PBP^{-1}$ and $C \sim D$ such that $C = PDP^{-1}$ with the same $P$ matrix.
Is there a name for the relation between $A$ and $C$?
Thank you.

Comment: Note that this is not a relation on $A, C$, since whether the relation holds also depends on $B, D$.

Comment: If all it takes is for $C$ to be similar to something with $P$, you do realize $C=P(P^{-1}CP)P^{-1}$ always, so that apparently every$C$ you try is “related to $A$”?

Comment: What do $B$ and $D$ have to do with anything?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how there can be a relation between $A$ and $C$ unless there is also a relation between $B$ and $D$ (equal, scalar multiples of each other, matrix multiples of each other, etc).

Comment: This seems a little bit overly reductive: are you saying two matrices have no relation unless they are exactly equal or scalar multiplies?  What if $D$ is a polynomial function of $B$?  Isn’t that a relation too?  But you do have a valid criticism of the question.

Comment: I would suppose that is also a relation, but when I answered, I'd assumed that all the matrices the OP was asking about involve only real numbers.

Comment: By polynomial function I just meant e.g. $D=B^2$, which certainly could happen with real-valued matrices.

Comment: I see. I changed my answer slightly to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

A similar, but more specific, situation does occur naturally: if both $B$ and $D$ are diagonal matrices, then $A$ and $C$ are said to be **simultaneously diagonalizable**.

So if $B$ and $D$ both belong to a special class of matrices, then you could very reasonably call this property “simultaneously X-izable”, where X might be diagonal, triangular, orthogonal, etc.

To be fair this isn’t so much a relation between $A$ and $C$ as it is a shared property of the two.  However it is a bit of a fine line: for instance, simultaneous diagonalizability only occurs in *commuting* families of matrices, which does feel more like a relation.